# How to find the water connection behind a shower wall?

Tags: water, walls, shower

I've inherited a half finished bath remodel. The shower panel mounting brackets are installed and there is an empty 2 inch diameter hole, 3 feet off the floor. The original shower head / handle was on the same wall. There is hardibacker behind the porcelain tiles.

Without causing too much damage, how can I find the cold/hot connections and attach them to my shower panel?

[image: shower wall]
[image: vigo shower panel]

Edit: This is the adjacent wall. Some of you suggested to go from this side. The toilet is about the same height as the shower hole.

[image: kohler persuade toilet]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is on the other side of the wall?  Cutting a hole in the drywall on the other side would be the preferred method.  If the 2" diameter hole is not large enough for both flex-lines, the you might need to enlarge it, or drill a 2nd hole through the tile and backerboard with an appropriate bit and lots of muscle.

Though.... if the contractor abandoned the job the tile job probably wasn't done right either and will leak meaning you will need to rip it down anyway.

Comment: Use a stud finder on the other side of wall. Find center of stud and cut drywall there so you can screw same piece of drywall back on when done and spackle.

Comment: The other side of the wall is a toilet room. It is not tiled. The toilet is adjacent to the shower panel.

Comment: @JustinK:  I agree.  Sheetrock is at least 10 times easier to repair than ceramic tile.  If there are no counters or other fixtures in the way, that is definitely the way to approach it.

Comment: Send us pictures!  You have an interesting mystery on your hands.  Was the contractor too lazy to drill the 2nd hole?

Comment: I've just attached a photo of the other side of the wall. After finding the hot and cold connections, should I attach flexible tubes to them and route them through the hole in the tile? How do I properly seal the hole to prevent moisture from entering? And what do you mean by the tile work wasn't done properly? Do you see something wrong with it or are you speculating? I saw the contractor cover the entire shower in something labeled as waterproof hardibacker before laying down the tiles. I hope that's enough to prevent leaks.

Comment: It is better to have hard plumbed connections go through the wall: they will be easier to caulk.  There are a lot of details that go into making a shower not leak: I'm only speculating that if the guy put in just one hole for the water, perhaps he missed other details.  Take photos from the rear once the drywall is out.